# Find what index an element is in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

In Python if you have a list:

```
list = [ cow , dog , cat ]
```

Is it possible to find what index an element is at?

Is there a command which does something like:

```
{some code}(cow)
```

and have it say something like
`cow = 0`?

Comment: going through pydocs would have given you answer instantaneously.

Answer (score 7):

Of course there is. Try

```
>>> ['cow', 'dog', 'cat'].index('cow')
0
```

May i suggest, don't use `list` as a variable name, as it is already used for constructing a list object.